# Is UTF-8 an encoding or a character set?

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8, character

I thought that the name of the character set was "Unicode" and that "UTF-8" was the name of a particular encoding of the Unicode character set, but I often see the terms "encoding" and "charset" used interchangeably when referring to UTF-8.

For example,

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

vs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is UTF-8 an encoding or a character set?

UTF-8 is an encoding and that term is used in the RFC that defines it which is quoted below.

---

> I often see the terms "encoding" and "charset" used interchangeably

Prior to Unicode, if you wanted to use an alphabet† like Cyrillic or Greek, you needed to use a encoding that only encoded to characters in that alphabet.  Thus, the terms *encoding* and *charset* were often conflated but they mean different things.

Now though, Unicode is usually the only character set you need to worry about since it contains characters for most written languages you'll have to deal with, except Klingon.

† - Alphabet, a kind of *character set* where characters correspond directly to sounds in a spoken language.

---

A *character set* is a mapping from code-units (integers) to characters, symbols, glyphs, or other marks in a written language.  Unicode is a character set that maps 21b integers to unicode codepoints.  The Unicode Consortium's [glossary](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#unicode) describes it thus:

> ## Unicode

> 1. The standard for digital representation of the characters used in writing all of the world's languages. Unicode provides a uniform means for storing, searching, and interchanging text in any language. It is used by all modern computers and is the foundation for processing text on the Internet. Unicode is developed and maintained by the Unicode Consortium: http://www.unicode.org.
> 2. A label applied to software internationalization and localization standards developed and maintained by the Unicode Consortium.

---

An *encoding* is a mapping from strings to strings.  UTF-8 is an encoding that maps strings of bytes (8b integers) to strings of code-points (21b integers).  The Unicode Consortium calls it a ["character encoding scheme"](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#character_encoding_scheme) and it is defined in [RFC 3629](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629).

> The originally proposed encodings of the UCS, however, were
> not compatible with many current applications and protocols, and this
> has led to the development of UTF-8

Comment: Didn't it [distinction between charset and encoding] apply even before unicode? For example the character set JIS X 0208 is encoded differently by EUC-JP and Shift-Jis

Comment: @Esailija, yes, but when there were many character sets that were tied to encodings, people were often exposed to them in a way that made charsets without a single corresponding encoding seem an exception to the rule rather than being introduced to two obviously distinct things that each need their own term.

Comment: Yep, "character set" and "charset" are just widely mis-used to refer to encodings. Especially, oddly enough, in MIME and related standards.

Answer (score 8):

UTF-8 is an *encoding*, in the sense that it *encodes* a sequence of abstract integers – the [unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) codepoints which indicate abstract characters – into a set of bytes.  (Through unicode spectacles, you could say that a 'character set' such as [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) is also a table-driven 'encoding', in the sense that it encodes a small number of codepoints as bytes, but this is verging towards an abuse of terminology, and probably isn't very helpful).

The sequence of integers is (in some fundamental sense) the 'unicode string', but in order to save these on a disk or send them over a network, you need to encode them as a sequence of bytes.  UTF-8 is one way of doing that, UTF-16 is another: one unicode string will be represented as two different streams of bytes if it's encoded in the two different ways.

---

There are multiple fine answers here, but just yesterday I spent some time trying to boil this issue down to some minimal size, so this provides a happy opportunity to reuse that text:

Joel Spolsky's article on [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) is quite good, I think.  It's (surely) been mentioned here before, but it bears repeating.  I think it's not completely minimal, though.

On the couple of occasions when I've had to explain 'unicode' to a colleague, it's been the notion of the abstract Unicode codepoints that's turned out key to the illumination.  The structure of my successful explanations has been something like this:

- The Unicode consortium has (with much agonising and negotiation) managed to give *a number* to a large fraction of the characters in use.  These numbers are (jargon) called 'codepoints'.
- 'The Letter A' has a codepoint, and this is independent of fonts.  Thus 'A' and 'a' have different codepoints, but roman, bold, italic, serif, sans serif (et very much cetera) are not distinguished.  Japanese kanji, tengwar and klingon characters (for example) have codepoints (this gets attention).
- A 'unicode string' is (conceptually) a sequence of codepoints.  This is a sequence of mathematical integers.  It does not make sense to ask whether these are bytes, 2-byte or 4-byte words; the sequence has nothing to do with computers.
- If, however, you want to send that sequence of integers to someone, or save it on a computer disk, you have to do something to encode it. You could also write down the sequence of numbers on a piece of paper, but let's specialise to computers at this point.  If you want to store or send this on a computer, you have to transform these integers into a sequence of bytes.  There are multiple procedures for doing that, and each of these procedures is named an 'encoding'.  One of these 'encodings' is UTF-8.
- When you 'read a Unicode file', you are starting with a sequence of bytes, on disk, and conceptually ending up with a sequence of integers.  If the 'unicode file' is indicated, somehow, to be encoded in UTF-8, then you have to decode that sequence of bytes to get the sequence of integers, using the algorithm defined in [RFC 3629](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3629.txt).  All of the subsequent operations on the 'unicode string' are defined in terms of the sequence of codepoints, and the fact that it started off, on disk, as 'UTF-8' is forgotten.

Comment: Correction: Tengwar and Klingon do not currently have Unicode codepoints allocated to them.  Both have indeed been proposed at various times, but neither proposal has a national standards body or industry player behind it, to supply the requisite committee slog.

Answer (score 3):

The Unicode Standard calls it an *encoding form* or an *encoding scheme*. Unicode has a single set of characters (known as the Unicode character set, or Universal Character Set), and all the UTF *encoding forms* and *encoding schemes* can encode all the characters in that set.

As happens with many other terms, programmers seem to have a tendency to just misappropriate terms here and there, and this is just one more instance of this.

Answer (score 2):

UTF-8 is an encoding. Encodings are however often called character sets, and many protocols therefore use the parameter name `charset` for a parameter that specifies character encoding. As such, `charset` is just an identifier.

Answer (score 2):

From all possible sources, UTF-8 is named as an *encoding*, not a *charset*, period.

**However** it was defined by Unicode Standard to primarily encode Unicode charset. Just check what the UTF acronym means: ***Unicode** Transformation Format*. It even gives some backward compatibility with some previous charset like ASCII. So from a practical point of view, it would be very unusual to use UTF-8 to encode a charset other than Unicode.

This might be the root of the inaccurate use of UTF-8 as a charset in some contexts.