# Is utf-8 a character set or an encoding?

Tags: html, unicode, utf-8

From what I understand, Unicode is a character set containing all possible characters in all languages. Utf-8 is a way to represent each of those characters in memory.
If it's the case, why do we put:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

and not

```
<meta encoding="utf-8">
```

in an html document to indicate an utf-8 encoding?

Comment: Surely this is a question of semantics? UTF-8 is a character set, you specify which character set your text is encoded with. Charset is just the standard attribute name for it.

Comment: Please make a research before asking.

Comment: Isn't uft-8 an encoding and unicode a character set? I mean, utf-8, utf-16 and utf-32 are all different ways to encode unicode but they're still used for the same character set!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a theoretical speculation, not a practical programming question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is UTF-8 an encoding or a character set?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15227667/is-utf-8-an-encoding-or-a-character-set)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<meta charset="foo">` is a mostly-compatible-by-luck abbreviation of the original HTML 2.0 `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=foo">` construct. `meta http-equiv` is used (in a limited way) to smuggle HTTP headers inside an HTML document, so this construct is equivalent to setting `charset=foo` on the `Content-Type` header of the enclosing HTTP response.

The `Content-Type` HTTP header was taken from the MIME standard originally used for e-mail (RFC2045, originally RFC1341). This standard called it `charset` because it predates Unicode. In those days, ISO-8559-1, cp1251 et al were considered separate character sets. It was only when Unicode came along that it reformulated them as encoded subsets of the One True character set.

Now that the web has standardised on Unicode (actually UTF-16 code units, more's the pity) as its character model it would indeed be more accurate to describe it as an `encoding`. But the name `charset` has stuck because there is no pressing need to fix it.

Comment: Much of the Internet has standardized on UTF-8, not on UTF-16.

Comment: @Remy: As an _encoding_, yes. As a character model JavaScript and the DOM interfaces all provide access to text data as sequences of UTF-16 code units, not UTF-8 bytes or full Unicode code points.

Comment: Many programing languages, especially scripting languages, have standardized on using UTF-16 for in-memory representation of text data, yes.

Comment: So what is your clear answer, whether it is character set or not? It would be much appreciated if you could write a clear statement on the same. From your answer and what I have read till now, as per this is an encoding scheme for Unicode character set.

Comment: The question states correctly that UTF-8 is an encoding. This answer is an explanation of why HTML documents call it a “charset” nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

UTF-8 is an encoding of Unicode; it's not really useful to think of it as a 'character set'.

Unicode is a long-term effort to enumerate 'glyphs' in a very large range of world writing systems (a 'glyph' is what you and I would call a character).  In Unicode, each of these characters is given a number – a 'codepoint' – which identifies it.  Thus the glyph 'a' (the latin lowercase letter 'a') is given codepoint number 97 (it's no coincidence that the codepoint for the first 126 characters are identical to their numbers in ASCII).

Thus a 'Unicode string' is a sequence of Unicode codepoints.  These are abstract integers.

If you want to actually serialise this sequence of codepoints to a file, or through a network, then you have to *encode* it as a sequence of bytes.  *That's* what an 'encoding' is.

UTF-8 is one of a few standard recipes for doing this encoding; UTF-16 and UTF-32 are two other standard ones, UCS-2 is a now-deprecated one.  UTF-8 is a method which takes a sequence of integers (these codepoints) and turns it into a sequence of bytes.  The [Wikipedia page on UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is pretty clear, I think.

Joel Spolsky has an excellent summary called [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) which is... well... what it says.

(*Terminology*: a 'character set' or 'codepage' is something like ASCII or ISO-8859-*n* (eg, the Latin-1 block, [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)) which is a fixed-size table which associates a number with a character.  This idea obviously overlaps somewhat with the idea of Unicode's 'list of all characters', and the fact that Unicode is sometimes described as a 'Universal Character Set' helps blur that distinction.  However Unicode's clear distinction between the abstract list of integers which is a 'unicode string', and its encoding into the sequence of bytes which appears on-disk, is a very valuable one.  When you've had the 'Aha!' moment and seen why that's a very useful idea, Unicode suddenly becomes very simple and obvious.)

Comment: Just after writing this, I see that there's a [similar question elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15227667/).  I even discovered that I added a very similar answer to that question....

Answer (score 1):

There used to be no distinction between those two. For example, ASCII defines certain bytes to represent certain letters. It can be called both an encoding and a character set. Or a "codepage" for that matter. Those are all closely related terms essentially meaning the same thing. An *"encoding"* defines how certain characters are encoded in bytes. A *"charset"* is a set of characters that can be represented by a computer [using a specific method]. A "*codepage*" is a "page" of codes that map to characters. All three terms essentially mean the same thing.

Only Unicode introduced an indirection between its "set of characters" and the physical encoding they're represented in. The same is not true for most other encodings/charsets/codepages.

They had to choose *some* term when they created HTML. They went with `charset`. It doesn't have any more or less meaning than if they'd chosen `encoding`.

Answer (score 0):

**"Character encoding is used to represent a repertoire of characters by some kind of an encoding system."** - Wikipedia.

UTF-8 is a character set. It defines which binary values represent a character in an encoding system. E.g. in UTF-8 a = 01100001. Without a charset, the web browser / server may choose to use a different value for the letter a. Which can lead to all sorts of issues.

In an HTML5 5 document you should put this inside the < head > tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

In an HTML 4.01 document you should put this inside the < head > tag::

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: UTF-8 is not a character set, see @bobince answer.